# Node.Js / Express app, https server and nginx

Tags: node.js, .htaccess, ssl, nginx

I have an Node.Js / Express app running on WebFaction servers.

I used to use `http` as the protocol then decided to switch to `https`.

Got the SSL certificate from Comodo, installed it, and as per WebFaction instructions set redirect so that all requests to `http://infranodus.com` are automatically forwarded by a server app (and `.htaccess` rule in that app) to `https://infranodus.com` which works fine.

(I guess they use nginx server in between)

So my question is: if I'm currently launching a server using

```
var http = require('http');
var app = express();
var appio = http.createServer(app);
```

Don't I also need to launch the server using `https` instead of `http` in my Node.Js / Express app?

It works the way it is now, but I'm just concerned about security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are supposed to upload your SSL certificate to their infrastructure, it usually means they run a load balancer at the edge of their network. A HTTPS connection is terminated there with your provided certificate, and a plain HTTP connection is forwarded to your application. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSL_termination_proxy

So your server can listen only for HTTP connections.